# C++ remove character from string

Tags: c++, string, character, stdstring, erase

I am currently trying to implement deleting characters from a text field in C++. If the user hits Backspace, the following code is executed. There is currently no cursor, it should just remove the last character...

```
if (mText.length() > 0){
    mText.erase( mText.length() - 1, 1);
    // mText.resize(mText.length() - 1);
}
```

This works fine the first time, but if you hit Backspace again, it does not remove anything.

I printed the `mText.length()` and it shows that the length never changes. I tried to `resize()` the string, it works fine, but the first time I hit Backspace it removes **2** characters.

I hope someone can explain this behaviour and help me solving the problem. I dont know much about memory allocation, so please be patient with me ;)

Thanks
*opatut*

Comment: Is mText a copy of your 'text field' variable and not the variable itself?

Comment: <code>private: std::string mText;</code> in class definition... so <code>pop_back</code> is no option...

Comment: is it possible you are inadvertently working with a *copy* of the string..and thus any modifications aren't reflected in the next iteration over user input? I'm only guessing here since we don't have the entire code context of the problem...

Comment: Both the resize and erase approach should work, the problem lies in another part of the code.

Comment: @Mike Ellery: I am not working with a copy, and the graphics are rendering without the last character from another method of that class. But then it fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my problem using gdb. I found the hidden `\b` escape sequence which was added to my string after I removed the last character. It actually stands for the backspace, but it was not interpreted. Thank you for your help!

```
"Roflcopt\b"
```

Answer (score 2):

According to [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/erase/), string.erase with a single size_t parameter will remove all characters from the specified position to the end of the string. A second size_t parameter may be provided for the number of characters to be deleted.

I checked this works as expected using http://www.ideone.com (look [here](http://ideone.com/wRmQd)) and also checked that string::length() works as expected.

I think the problem is elsewhere..

Comment: Huh. Looks like Codepad.org with more supported languages.

Answer (score 1):

Why not try `if(!mText.empty())mText = mText.substr(0, mText.length()-1);`?

Comment: hm, did not think of substr... but this is not working either. <code>mText.length();</code> does not change

Comment: Why not just `pop_back()`? Or at the least `erase`/`resize` it.

Comment: @opatut: Well.. If you are using the code as I've given then it shud change it. Unless you're not setting mText to be the text of the text-field or you're re-reading the value of the text-field back into mText just after this statement. And, as GMan said, there's always `pop_back()`. I'm not sure which C++ library you're using here. But if it's standard C++ compliant library, std::string and std::wstring does have pop_back().

Comment: std::string has pop_back? I don't find it here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/ and my compiler complains about it...

Comment: @opatut @Vite: Indeed, there is no `pop_back`. (In the C++03 standard. There is in the C++0x standard, though I didn't realize that was an addition and is what I had in mind.) All the more reason to claim the standard library is poorly designed; free-functions are better than member functions.